# Reduce Variance of monte carlo estimator using guess of mean

Tags: bayesian, variance, prior, estimators

Suppose you have a random variable $X$ and black-box function $f$. Suppose you also have prior estimates $m$ and $s$ of the mean and standard deviation of $f(X)$.

How can we use this prior information to reduce the variance of a Monte Carlo estimator of the mean of $f(X)$?

Thanks ahead of time!

**my attempts**

My first idea was to just treat $m$ as a sample, and give it a weight $w$ based on how accurate $m$ is. We could form the estimator
$$E[f(X)] \approx \frac{1}{n}\left(wm + \sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i)\right)$$

Alternatively, we could use importance sampling by sampling $X$ from, say, a Gaussian $N(m,s^2)$.